# How to add rows at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports

using crystal report 7

```
ID Value total

001 100 2000
002 300 1000
003 300 1000
......
```

i want to add one more additional row at runtime after 2nd row (1st + 2nd row).

Expected Ouput

```
ID Value total subtotal

001 100 2000 (a)
002 300 1000 (b)
123 400 3000 (total of a & b)
003 300 1000 (c)
......
```

How to do it in crystal report.

Can any one give me a idea or formula help

Comment: is it just one single row? or do you need a row below `(d)` which is the `(total of c & d)` and so on? your best approach will probably be to create a group and place your total line in the group footer. the tricky bit will be determining what to group on and which suppression formula to use to ensure the totals only appear where you want them

Comment: I want to make a single row (a + b) only, no need of (c + d).....,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a new formula field: `if recordnumber in [1,2] then 1 else 2;`
- Create a group using this formula
- Suppress the group header
- Conditionally suppress the group footer using formula `recordnumber > 2`
- Add your total fields to the group footer

Comment: I already using one group by ID, now i have to create another group or in the same group i have to do...?

Comment: You will need to create another group outside of your existing group (so the new one will be group level 1, and your existing group will become group level 2). if there's more than one row in each group the `recordnumber` formula will need to be tweaked a little too