# How to sum of the specified column value

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 7

```
ID Value

001 100
002 200
003 400
004 500
...
```

I have n number of row, from that i want to sum of value from 003 to n, i don't want to sum of 001 and 002.

In a report footer, i need to add sum of value from 003 to n.

How to create a formula for the above condition, Need formula help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same solution as: [How to add rows at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953053/how-to-add-rows-at-runtime)

- Create a new formula field: `if {table.id} in ['001', '002'] then 1 else 2;`
- Create a group using this formula
- Suppress the group header
- Add your total fields to the group footer (you will get a total of 001 + 002 then a total of 003... n

Comment: thank you for your reply, then 1 else 2 means...? i am understand what this formula will do...?

Comment: it means `if` the `id` is `001` or `002` then group them together in a group we call `1`... if the id is anything `else` then group them together in a group we call `2`

Comment: Actually i want to add 001 + 002 only, i don't want to sum of other id's.  your answer showing error as group specified on a non-recurring field

Comment: Can you paste your formula? It normally means you're using an aggregate function or not directly referring to your recordset

Comment: Exact formula - if {TEMPSHED.code} in ['001', '002'] then Sum ({@sssBudget}, {@cOrder}) else 0;

Comment: It should be if {TEMPSHED.code} in ['001', '002'] then 1 else 2;

Comment: 1 means value 1 is displaying, it is not displaying sum of value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9529/discussion-between-lee-tickett-and-jetjack)